# Unable to compile AWS CustomIdentityProvider on xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, beta, xcode8-beta6

I am using Amazon Cognito and Facebook login in an ios app. Up until beta 5 this code [from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597388/aws-cognito-swift-credentials-provider-logins-is-deprecated-use-awsidentitypro) worked:

```
class CustomIdentityProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    var tokens: [NSString: NSString]?

    init(tokens: [NSString: NSString]) {
        self.tokens = tokens
    }

    @objc func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        return AWSTask(result: tokens) // Compile error in beta 6
    }
}
```

In beta 6 I get this compile error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[NSString:NSString]?' to expected argument type '_?'
```

When I change the line to

```
return AWSTask(result: tokens! as [AnyObject: AnyObject])
```

I get the error

```
Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

This is swift ver. 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast to NSDictionary instead of a Swift Dictionary:

```
return AWSTask(result: tokens! as NSDictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) Which is quite obvious.