# AWS and Changes in Swift 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, swift3

After the Swift 3 update, I'm having some trouble getting my app to compile. Most of the errors are pretty simple to fix, but I'm running into a few in particular with AWS. Is there some sort of updated AWS SDK for Swift 3? I've tried to look it up, but haven't found one. In any case, the two main errors I'm having trouble resolving are as follows:

"Type 'IdentityProviderManager' does not conform to protocol AWSIdentityProviderManager." This is for a class I created following a tutorial to set up logins through AWS Cognito. The code is:

```
class IdentityProviderManager: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager{
var tokens : [NSString : NSString]?
init(tokens: [NSString : NSString]) {     
    self.tokens = tokens 
}    
@objc func logins() -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {
    return AWSTask(result: tokens as AnyObject)
}
```

}

In the AWS documentation for AWSIdentityProviderManager, it says that the only required function is logins, which I have. Is there a simple way to resolve this that I'm missing?

The other error is in my LoginViewController class: "Type 'LoginViewController' does not conform to protocol 'AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication'." Here the issue seems a bit more clear, since the documentation says that getPasswordAuthenticationDetails() is a required method and XCode seems to have changed this method to getDetails() when updating to Swift 3, unless I'm mistaken and it wasn't there to begin with or something. In any case, autocomplete doesn't give me the original method and I can't seem to make the class conform to the protocol.

Apologies if the answer is already in documentation somewhere, but as far as I can tell it seems like the AWS SDK (at least the version that I have) is somehow incompatible with Swift 3. Is there something I can do to resolve these errors?

Comment: Your code wasn't working for me, but this fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045869/unable-to-compile-aws-customidentityprovider-on-xcode-8-beta-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it turned out XCode just wasn't showing me the option to make the changes I needed. The automatic fix implemented slightly different versions of the required functions and everything ended up working.