# API Gateway generated SDK for iOS (Objective-C) with Cognito User Pool for authorized users

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ios, amazon-cognito

I have deployed an API using AWS API Gateway and I am trying to access it through an iOS device. Some endpoints support unauthorized users and I have no trouble accessing them but others don't and I can't manage to query them. I use the new Cognito User Pool feature for authentication which works fine when using a web application (or postman).

First, even though some of the endpoints are protected (like in the following picture of the console), when I deploy the API and generate the SDK for iOS (Objective-C), I can read in the README file: "All endpoints do not require authorization."

[image]

Then, when I run the following authentication code from AWS documentation, everything seems to work just fine:

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionEUWest1 credentialsProvider:nil];
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *userPoolConfiguration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:ClientId  clientSecret:nil poolId:UserPoolId];
[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:userPoolConfiguration forKey:@"UserPool"];
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

AWSCognitoIdentityUser *user = [pool getUser];
[[user getSession:username password:password validationData:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *> *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not get user session. Error: %@", task.error);
    } else if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"Could not get user session. Exception: %@", task.exception);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved user session data");
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *session = (AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *) task.result;

        NSMutableString *poolId = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"];
        [poolId appendString:UserPoolId];
        NSString *tokenStr = [session.idToken tokenString];
        NSDictionary *tokens = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tokenStr, poolId, nil];



        CognitoPoolIdentityProvider *idProvider = [[CognitoPoolIdentityProvider alloc] init];
        [idProvider addTokens:tokens];

        AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionEUWest1 identityPoolId:IdentityPoolId identityProviderManager:idProvider];

        [credentialsProvider clearKeychain];
        [credentialsProvider clearCredentials];

        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionEUWest1
                                                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

        [[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<NSString *> * _Nonnull task) {
            if (task.error) {
                NSLog(@"Could not get identity id: %@", task.error);
            } else if (task.exception) {
                NSLog(@"Could not get identity id: %@", task.exception);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Identity id: %@", task.result);
            }

            return nil;
         }];
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

I implemented CognitoPoolIdentityProvider as specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597388/aws-cognito-swift-credentials-provider-logins-is-deprecated-use-awsidentitypro).

```
@interface CognitoPoolIdentityProvider ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *tokens;
@end

@implementation CognitoPoolIdentityProvider

    - (AWSTask<NSDictionary *> *)logins {
        return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.tokens];
    }

    - (void)addTokens:(NSDictionary *)tokens {
        self.tokens = tokens;
    }

@end
```

I manage to get a proper token (tested using postman) and a user id:

> 2016-12-27 12:43:35.760 AskHub[26625:10037234] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.11 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
>   {"IdentityId":"eu-west-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}
>   2016-12-27 12:43:35.766 AskHub[26625:10037234] Identity id: eu-west-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

However, when I run the following code to hit a protected endpoint, CloudFront considers that I am not authenticated.

```
APIHealthClient *apiClient = [APIHealthClient defaultClient];
APIAskHubRequest *initReq = [[APIAskHubRequest alloc] init];
initReq.message = @"FIN";

NSLog(@"Sending initial request");
[[apiClient webhooksAskhubPost:initReq] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not send initial request: %@", task.error);
    } else if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"Could not send initial request: %@", task.exception);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully sent initial request");
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Reponse:

> 2016-12-27 12:56:25.247 AskHub[26784:10046562] Could not send initial request: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPBody={
>       message = Unauthorized;
>   }, HTTPHeaderFields={type = immutable dict, count = 9,
>   entries =>
>       3 : Via = {contents = "X.X XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"}
>       4 : x-amzn-ErrorType = {contents = "UnauthorizedException"}
>       5 : Content-Type = {contents = "application/json"}
>       6 : Content-Length = {contents = "27"}
>       7 : Connection = {contents = "keep-alive"}
>       8 : x-amzn-RequestId = {contents = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}
>       9 : Date = {contents = "Tue, 27 Dec 2016 11:56:25 GMT"}
>       10 : X-Cache = {contents = "Error from cloudfront"}
>       11 : X-Amz-Cf-Id = {contents = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
>   }
>   }

Am I missing something here? Does the automatically generated SDK support User Pool authentication?

Comment: I am having the same exact problem you are having... I have an api that has authorization through my cognito user pool. When I call this api through postman with passed in "Authorization" header with a valid id token from a user in my user pool, it works. However, when I try to call the same api through ios with the generated api ios sdk, I get the same error. My guess is that one more thing in ios is not setup yet? I'm going to keep chugging along and post back here if I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that there is a confusion here between two types of authentication modes: using a credentials provider or just adding the JWT token to the "Authorization" header parameter (or your custom parameter name if you specified one when creating your authorizer).

The first method did not work for me, even though it is the only one that I have found in the documentation when it comes to using the iOS SDK. The second method works pretty fine, but to be able to use it without hacking into the SDK, don't forget to add the "Authorization" header when you specify your API in API Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the code I see, you are clearing credentials but never getting credentials.  On quick review it looks like you are setting up the service configuration and authentication correctly, but you never call credentials.

If that was the case, even though your application would authenticate, the credentials provider would never go get the logins dictionary.

(You can verify this in the AWS Console, if you look at the identityId you are trying to use to access the resource, you can look at the "logins" count.  If it is 0, you are not logged in.)

In order to be authenticated you need to have the credentials provider call your identityProviderManager "logins" method.

That call happens when you do "getCredentialsForIdentity" which is "credentials" in the SDK.

Typically the sequence is GetID followed by GetCredentialsForId.  In the IOS SDK, the GetId happens with "getSession" (so you should have that), and the GetCredentials happens with "credentials"

(Note that there are different SDKs with different naming in each (Mobile Hub vs IOS SDK for example) but all that matters is that your credentials provider gets a login dictionary. With verbose logging you should actually see the "logins" dictionary logged, which will prove to you that a logins dictionary is being provided to the credentials provider).

Comment: Thanks for precising things. I tried to call "credentials" and it seems to work since I am able to log the AccessKey, the SecretKey and the SessionKey. However, when I set the defaultServiceConfiguration afterwards (using the new credentialsProvider) and then I call the API, I still get an UnauthorizedException...

Comment: Do you get the logins dictionary in your log file?  Like this: "X-Amz-Target" = "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity";
}
2016-12-27 17:09:30.736 KeyCode[3004:122424] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.14 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:555 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request body:
{"Logins":{"cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx”:”eyJraWQixxxxxxxxxx long long coded tokenxxxxxj3f2QzWX5o8AVdtDPA"},"IdentityId":"us-east-1:”}

Comment: do you get logins to be greater than 0 in the aws console for the identityId in question?

Comment: Yes I do get the logins dictionary, the only difference is that I have AWSURLSessionManager.m line:543 instead of line: 555. I guess we use different versions of the SDK, can you please let me know which one do you use if it works. Logins is greater than 0, it was 1 and to be sure, I created a new user and executed my code with the new login/password and now I have 2 identities in the console.

Comment: So: you are logged in and authenticated. Am I correct that we can dismiss the IAM policies because what is failing in the IOS app is working in the web app? If so, make sure that: 1) the Role that is failing is the Authenticated Role ( see this in the logs). 2) That the App Client id from the user pool for your app matches the one used in authentication providers in Federated config, (and if you create an identity provider, not usually needed, in IAM, make sure the audience matches the App Client ID).

Comment: Also - are you working with a single federated pool? Has it changed? GetId policy CONTAINs the id(s) of the identity pool (though that seems to be working), and trust policies contain the ids of the trusted federated pool id.

Comment: Lastly, are you sure that the service that you are attempting to use has been registered with the service configuration you are using?  Actually.. .check that first.

Comment: Isn't this line enough for registering the service: [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:userPoolConfiguration forKey:@"UserPool"];. Also, I discovered an intersting fact: when connecting with the webapp or postman, the number of identities in the console does not increase. Since all I do is add the jwtToken to the Authorizer field in the HTTP header, I suppose this does not trigger an AssumeRole process unlike what happens in my iOS app...

Comment: I tried to add a few permissions like "execute-api:Invoke" to the associated authenticated IAM role, but the problem presists.

Comment: Well I don't know what APIHealthClient is or what services it is trying to use but usually each of the services needs to be registered when initialized. The registration you did does register user pools so you can log in, and I am a bit out of my depth ( I don't know cloud front) but don't you have to register some AWS service you are attempting to use?

Comment: APIHealthClient is part of the SDK automatically generated by APIGateway (My API is called "Health" with "API" as a prefix). I don't quite see what I have to register but the point you raised about Federated Identities is quite interesting. It seems to me like, by adding the right token to the "Authorization" field in my HTTP request (which I manually do in my webapp also) is enough, and I don't need to assume any role using cognito (which explains the non-increasing identities counter in the Federated Identity)...

Comment: I suspect the increasing identities counter is caused by your app always clearing the keychain.  The clear credentials call or some other call you make will then get a new identityId.  Then authenticate and you go back and get the same old (cleared) identity and in that process you will abandon the other identity (and will never be able to access it again, I believe it will be marked as DISABLE (console has a typo... without a d, but it means DISABLED) in the console.

Comment: I finally managed to properly hit the API by doing exactly what I did in the webapp. I added an "Authorization" header parameter in the API specification (the generated SDK is adapted accordingly) then I fill it directly with the token. The documentation provided on that part is terribly misleading to my view, even though I may have missed something. Anyway, thanks a lot Bruce for your help and happy new year!

Comment: All you did was add the "Authorization" header in the method request of the API and regenerated ios sdk? I've had that header and it still won't work for me. Did you select "Caching" next to that header? Is the identity token source for your cognito authorizer: "method.request.header.Authorization"?