# Generality of AWS Sample Code for credentialsProvider.logins deprecation

Tags: aws-mobilehub, amazon-cognito

I have an iOS app that has been using AWS MobileHub and SNS. While upgrading to MobileHub 2.4.14 I encountered the deprecation of credentialsProvider.logins. The only solution I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597388/aws-cognito-swift-credentials-provider-logins-is-deprecated-use-awsidentitypro) SO post directing me to [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample) AWS Sample code which seemed to address my situation even though it was written for developer authenticated identities and was targeted to CognitoSync (I just want SNS).

After adapting the sample code to my app I get the following runtime error message after receiving my Cognito security token:

```
2017-02-10 17:19:18.449 XXXX[9808:4068888] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.14 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"message":"Identity pool isn't set up for SNS"}
2017-02-10 17:19:18.450 XXXX[9808:4068888] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.14 [Error] AWSCognitoService.m line:338 | __37-[AWSCognito registerDeviceInternal:]_block_invoke.262 | Unable to register device: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoSyncErrorDomain Code=5 "Identity pool isn't set up for SNS" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=InvalidConfigurationException:, NSLocalizedDescription=Identity pool isn't set up for SNS}
```

The error message doesn't tell me exactly what's wrong. I'm using the same identity pool that I was using before the upgrade. The SNS role of my identity pool already has permission for all SNS related actions.

It bothers me that the error is in the AWSCognitoSyncErrorDomain and I'm not wanting to use CognitoSync. Is this error a side-effect of the sample code? Is there sample code that addresses the credentialsProvider.logins deprecation without involving CognitoSync?

Thanks