# Unable to login using AWS Cognito and access tokens

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the cognito identity using access tokens that I retrieved from my identity provider. A little bit like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597388/aws-cognito-swift-credentials-provider-logins-is-deprecated-use-awsidentitypro). There seem to be an issue with this part of the AWS SDK as described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/357), so I am trying to find a work-around.

When I run the code I am getting the following error:

> Task
>   result: nil Error   Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Invalid login token.
>   Issuer doesn't match providerName}

Below my code, I suspect that the problem is the way I set up the logins in here:

**idInput?.logins = ["provider_url": idToken]** // Do I need some other parameter?

Code:

```
func congitoAuthentication(accessToken : String, idToken : String, refreshToken : String) {
    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUWest1, identityPoolId: "eu-west-2:XXXX")

    let serviceConfig = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfig
    let idInput = AWSCognitoIdentityGetIdInput()
    idInput?.identityPoolId = "eu-west-2:XXXX"
    idInput?.logins = ["provider_url": idToken]

    let identity = AWSCognitoIdentity.default()

    let task = identity.getId( idInput!).continueWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as? NSError {
            print("Error   \(error)")
            return nil
        }

        return nil
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your "provider_url" is the type "cognito-idp.xxx"? it seems you are passing an invalid "provider_url"

Comment: thank you for your reply. Would you be able to clarify what you mean? Am I using the incorrect dictionary key for "provider_url"? How do you now that it is an invalid "provider_url"? Thanks !

Comment: because of the error msg. don't need to post here the full provider url, but what type of url is? it start with cognito-idp? so is a user cognito pool? or is a federated provider?